# Multiple Meta key in search

Tags: plugins, wp-query, query

I have a wordpress plugin which will search students result from database.IF i enter Roll number, It will display the result.Now, I would like to modify this as if i enter mobile phone number of student ,it should also show the result. The code is below

```
    enter // ResultPress search function
function result_press_search() {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['search'] ) )
        exit;

    query_posts(
            array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'no_found_rows' => true,
            'post_type' => 'rrf-result',
            'meta_key' => 'roll',
            'meta_value' => wp_unslash( ( string ) $_POST['search'] ),
            'rrf_result_year' => wp_unslash( ( string ) $_POST['result_year'] ),
        )
    );

    include_once( 'templates/marksheet-theme-1.php' );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Very hard to help if we don't know what the database looks like... but my guess is that you would want to change the meta_key to match the phone field and the meta_value to get the phone number value. If you want to have multiple meta queries, you will need to use Meta Queries -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Yes, I need multiple.If i change the "roll"  to "info_3" , it searches Mobiles number.but i need both. I am not sure about Meta Queries .Appreciate if you give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to switch between using query_posts (not recommended), to using [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Using WP Query is similar to query_posts, you will pass an array of arguments, and include the meta_query args. Something like:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'post_type' => 'rrf-result',
    'rrf_result_year' => wp_unslash( ( string ) $_POST['result_year'] ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'roll',
            'value' => wp_unslash( ( string ) $_POST['search'] ),
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'info_3',
            'value' => wp_unslash( ( string ) $_POST['search'] )
        )
    ) 
);



$results = new WP_Query($args);
```

If you have any results, you can access them by manually looping through `$results->posts` or by using the wordpress methods:

```
if($results->have_posts()):
    while($results->have_posts():
        $results->the_post();
        // do something here
    endwhile;
endif;
```

In your case I don't know exactly what you need because you are including another template part, and I don't know what's in it. I am also not sure if the plugin you are using modifies the query in any way.